# Icons become blurry with viewport and pixel density on different devices

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport

I am using viewport and media queries to make my site mobile friendly.

```
<meta name='viewport'content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0'>
```

I have a button with a background like so:

```
button{
 width:29px;
 height:29px;
 border:1px solid white;
 background:url(add.jpg);
}
```

It looks very simple like so on a computer:

[image]

On a high pixel density device, the viewport tag is needed display the website properly. But the images are stretched to display in the new viewport dimensions.

[image]

As you can see, even the image is uploaded bigger. So 29px is actually rendered like a 58px on a mobile device (depending on which device). And the image is stretched.

Are there any solutions for this? The only one I've found is to not use an image. Any ideas?

Comment: If you need an image, either use one for each media query rule, or a bigger one that scale down. A scale down image doesn't crack as a scale up one does.

Comment: What is the resolution of `add.jpg`? Also, https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-right-way-to-retinafy-your-websites--net-31793

Comment: It is 72ppi I believe

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` and `min-resolution` media queries to supply a 58-by-58 pixel image to be used on higher-DPI displays.

This example assumes you have created a new image for the high DPI display called `add@2x.jpg`. (The `@2x` suffix is a convention commonly used in native iOS app development, but you can name the file anything you want.)

```css
button{
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: url(add.jpg);

  @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    background: url(add@2x.jpg);
    background-size: 29px 29px;
  }
}
```

It's important to set the `background-size` property in order to "shrink" the image to the size that you expect it to be rendered in [CSS pixels](https://juiceboxinteractive.com/blog/a-pixel-is-not-a-pixel-designing-for-a-new-generation-of-mobile-devices/).

If you want to supply an image optimized for even higher-resolution devices, like an iPhone X, you can add an additional media query:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3), (min-resolution: 288dpi) { 
  background: url(add@3x.jpg);
  background-size: 29px 29px;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Will give it a go.

Comment: Where did you get 192dpi from? Just curious.

Comment: I tried this, It didn't work. I am using chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is to use and SVG. Use Illustrator to create an icon and use it as if it were a regular image in the website.

```
background: url(add.svg);
```

This is a universal solution that will work with all resolutions now and in the future.